# Level Metering UIView

Tags: xcode

How could I move a subview to the front of the stack when the LevelMeter detects a certain amount of decibels? I want LevelMetering to be active in real time without a record play function.

Ultimately, I'm trying to animate a mouth to open and close based on sound.

Answer (score 1):

To make a view topmost in the view order, you just have to send a `-bringSubviewToFront:` to the view that contains it. From a view controller, you might do something like:

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:levelMeterView];
```

If that doesn't answer your question, perhaps you can expand a bit on what you're asking?

Comment: I believe you mean to say :`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:levelMeterView];` from a view controller.

Comment: Thank you but I was asking about attaching the level metering function within the AVAudioRecorder class to affect subviews. I apologize about the awkward wording